# Using PHP to log value in header conditionally

Tags: php, mobile, opera-mini

I'm pretty new to PHP so please bear with me.

I'm trying to log the User Agents for mobile phones accessing my site. I'm doing this by checking the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] value.

Ran into a small issue where I noticed if the person was accessing my site via opera mini then opera mini moves the actual user agent into a header value identified as X-OperaMini-Phone-UA:

So I'm looking for the PHP code which will extract this from the header (if present) and if not, identify it as NA for database logging purposes.

This is the code I'm currently using for logging which was written by someone else

```
<?php
mysql_connect('server.com', 'dbuser', 'dbpass');
$url = mysql_real_escape_string("http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
$fn = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ref = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$ua = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
mysql_select_db('db');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `record` VALUES ('$url', '$fn', NOW(),'$ip', '$ref','$ua')");
?>
```

So, now I'm adding a few field named opera_user_agent and I want to log the Opera user agent if there is one and use 'NA' if there isn't.

Comment: Could you show relevant parts of your logging code? Where do you pick up `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, and how do you store it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the value with [getallheaders](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php):

```
$headers = getallheaders();

if (array_key_exists("X-OperaMini-Phone-UA", $headers))
{
    $ua = mysql_real_escape_string($headers["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"]);
}
else 
{
    $ua = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}
```

Another approach is to add the header to an environment variable with a rewriterule in .htaccess, and then pick it up via `$_SERVER` as usual:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=X-OPERAMINI-PHONE-UA:%{HTTP:X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}]
```

Comment: I would use the function alias `getallheaders()`. This method is avaiable under NSAPI too, and under FastCGI if you're running `PHP >= 5.4.0`, which you're probably not.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that but that only answers one part, how do I log it conditionally?

Comment: @Michael: I have updated the answer with a more elaborate example. To get further, you must show how you currently do the logging.

Comment: The thing is I still want to retain the fact that an Opera Mini browser accessed the page that's why I added the additional field. Alternatively I could just pre-pend some text if the value was logged via the X-opera header but don't know how to do that. What I'm trying to say is that I need the original User Agent but I also need to know if I got it from Opera or not

Comment: Michael: Then you will have to either add a field to your `record` table and add the (possibly empty) opera mini header to the `insert` query, or concatenate the strings. Concatenation is done with `.` in php.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']` as well:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])){
    // use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']
}else{
    // use default $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On October 2012 Opera suggested new header called `Device-Stock-UA`. After that time new Opera Mini/Mobile browsers will use new `Device-Stock-UA` and old `X-OperaMini-Phone-UA` headers.
https://dev.opera.com/blog/introducing-device-stock-ua/

This parameter is defined like this:

> The value of this header matches that of the stock user agent bundled
>   with the operating system on which Opera Mobile or Mini is running.

Regarding to that update I created this function:

```
public static function getUserAgentDevice() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'];
    }
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'];
    }
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}
```